# How to check if component returns false in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which I'm trying to refactor

```
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
<ListItemText
        primary={edit ? 
            <TextareaAutosize ... />
           : <Typography ..../>}
      />
```

The `TextareaAutosize` repeats a lot through the app so I thought I would convert it into a separate component.

```
export default function Textarea(props) {
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
    if(edit){
        return(
            <TextareaAutosize .../>
        )
    }
    return false
}
```

As you can see, if `edit` is false the component returns false. The back at the top I thought I would do this

```
import Textarea from "../Textarea";
<ListItemText
        primary={Textarea ? 
            <Textarea ... />
           : <Typography ..../>}
      />
```

By my logic, there should be a way to check if component `Textarea` will return false, right?

Comment: A component should return JSX, not a simple value. Your first example makes more sense.

Comment: @Andy Must it return JSX, is there no way to check if it returns false.

Comment: You could push down the logic into a single new component, which renders conditionally Textarea or Typography based on the edit flag. This way the common component always return JSX and you don't have to duplicate the condition everytime.

Comment: @FedericoRoma Yes but textarea is the complicated identical part, the Typography is different on different instances. You are correct normally but I'm wondering if it can be check whether a component with return JSX or false

Comment: Then you could pass "the other component" as a prop too, like: <EditableTextArea edit={...} fallback={<Typography .../>} .. />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "component" (JSX) is a UI element. You must return JSX or null, and the rendering engine will render the returned JSX or nothing if null.

You can check a flag and short-circuit:

```
{isFlag && <MyComponent ... />}
```

or have the component render or not (or if you want to keep state just show/hide):

```
<MyComponent isVisible={isFlag} />
```

Or possible return different components depending on flags:

```
if (isLoading) {
  return <MyLoadingSkeletonComponent />
}
<MyMainUIComponent />
```

**EDIT:**
You may want to refactor into a compound component where you take the flag and hide the show/hide logic within it

```
const TextArea = ({edit, editMode, viewMode}) => (
  edit ? editMode : viewMode
)

// Call it with the flag and both components:

<TextArea
   edit={edit}
   editMode={<TextareaAutosize ... />}
   viewMode={<Typography ... />}
/>
```

Comment: There is a way. The component is just a function that returns JSX so you could call it and test the return type. But don't do that. Use the techniques from the comments and answers.

Comment: we need to check returns of component to do actions . this is a case that we dont know component what will returns

Answer (score 0):

Have the best of the two worlds, your idea of refactoring is correct, but it is missing something.

try something like this:

```
export default function Textarea(props) {
  props.edit ? <TextareaAutosize .../> : <Typography ..../>
}
```

and

```
<ListItemText
        primary=<TextareaAutosize {edit} ... />
      />
```

In this case you have one place to change TextareaAutosize and Typography codes, less messy code in parent listing.

Hope this helps.